# How to global a Mysql connection OUT of a class to legacy code

Tags: php, mysql

I am converting a legacy site over to Class Driven MVC style site.

I have a fully functional DAL layer instantiated by a Super Class ($Sys). I can global the DB class just fine so that legacy code can: $Sys->Db->Query("sql here") ... tastes great, less filling.

Except there are hundreds and hundreds of straight mysql calls. ie: mysql_query("sql here").

All the legacy mysql calls rely upon the credentials/connection established by a db.inc file (which I want to get rid of).

Question: Is there any way to have the object "global" the connection / credentials established by the Object/DAL so that they are natively available to the legacy mysql calls? Ergo, the native mysql calls will run without the need to execute code outside the object?

Comment: Does your db class use a regular mysql handle internally? You could just put `$global_dbh = $Sys->Db->handle` or something into the 'old' db.inc.

Answer (score 0):

In one my project we use Zend Framework side-by-side with legacy code. We fetch db connection params from our DAL (Zend_Db) and set up connection for legacy code:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();
$dbParms = $db->getConfig();
$db2 = mysql_connect($dbParms['host'], $dbParms['username'], $dbParms['password'])
        or die("Could not connect:" . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbParms['dbname']) or die("Could not select database");
```

Comment: I am hoping to eliminate having to run code outside of the object that reaches into the object. I was wanting the object to "push", which I know breaks all sorts of "best principals" :-)